# MySQL LEFT JOIN ignores AND criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a functional LEFT JOIN MySQL query structured like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(HTG_ScheduleRequest.ID) AS current_job,
    HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber, 
    HTG_TechProps.EmpFirstName, 
    HTG_TechProps.EmpLastName,  
    HTG_TechProps.Veh_Number
     FROM HTG_TechProps 
        LEFT JOIN HTG_ScheduleRequest ON HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber = HTG_ScheduleRequest.SSR 
        AND (HTG_ScheduleRequest.ScheduleDateCurrent = CURDATE() || HTG_ScheduleRequest.ScheduleDateExact = CURDATE())
        AND RecordType = '1' 
        AND HTG_ScheduleRequest.JobStatus IN (2,5,8,3,4,7)   
        GROUP BY HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber ORDER BY HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber ASC
```

I need to add some criteria to the initial SELECT table like this:

```
HTG_TechProps.EmpStatus='A'
```

I get a Syntax error when I add a WHERE statement prior to the LEFT JOIN and when I add an AND like this after the LEFT JOIN it is ignored an still returning records that are not equal to A.

```
LEFT JOIN HTG_ScheduleRequest ON HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber = HTG_ScheduleRequest.SSR      
AND HTG_TechProps.EmpStatus='A'
```

Comment: Add the `WHERE` after the `JOIN`...

Comment: WHERE comes after the JOIN. Learn to use proper syntax.

Comment: Please qualify all column names so we know where they come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions on the first table in a `LEFT JOIN` should go in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(sr.ID) AS current_job,
       tp.EmpNumber, tp.EmpFirstName, tp.EmpLastName, tp.Veh_Number
FROM HTG_TechProps tp LEFT JOIN
     HTG_ScheduleRequest sr
     ON tp.EmpNumber = sr.SSR AND
        (sr.ScheduleDateCurrent = CURDATE() OR sr.ScheduleDateExact = CURDATE()
        ) AND
        sr.RecordType = '1' AND  -- assume this comes from SR
        sr.JobStatus IN (2, 5, 8, 3, 4, 7)   
WHERE tp.EmpStatus='A'
GROUP BY tp.EmpNumber  -- this is okay assuming that it is unique or (equivalently) a primary key
ORDER BY tp.EmpNumber ASC;
```

Note that this introduces table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, appreciate the assist.

Answer (score 0):

You should Use OR

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(HTG_ScheduleRequest.ID) AS current_job,
    HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber, 
    HTG_TechProps.EmpFirstName, 
    HTG_TechProps.EmpLastName,  
    HTG_TechProps.Veh_Number
FROM HTG_TechProps 
LEFT JOIN HTG_ScheduleRequest ON HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber = HTG_ScheduleRequest.SSR 
        AND (HTG_ScheduleRequest.ScheduleDateCurrent = CURDATE() OR  HTG_ScheduleRequest.ScheduleDateExact = CURDATE())
        AND RecordType = '1' 
        AND HTG_ScheduleRequest.JobStatus IN (2,5,8,3,4,7)   
GROUP BY HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber 
ORDER BY HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber ASC
```

and if you want apply where condtion for main table's columns you could use   where  eg:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(HTG_ScheduleRequest.ID) AS current_job,
    HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber, 
    HTG_TechProps.EmpFirstName, 
    HTG_TechProps.EmpLastName,  
    HTG_TechProps.Veh_Number
FROM HTG_TechProps 
LEFT JOIN HTG_ScheduleRequest ON HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber = HTG_ScheduleRequest.SSR 
         AND HTG_ScheduleRequest.JobStatus IN (2,5,8,3,4,7)   
WHERE (HTG_ScheduleRequest.ScheduleDateCurrent = CURDATE() OR  HTG_ScheduleRequest.ScheduleDateExact = CURDATE())
AND HTG_TechProps.RecordType = '1' 
GROUP BY HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber 
ORDER BY HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber ASC
```